# Transformation of random variable from X to Y

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, transformation

The two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are converted by $Y=g(X)$ as shown in the following equation. Find the probability density function of the random variable $Y$ when the probability density function of the random variable $X$ has a uniform distribution as follows.

Problem and solution:

[image: Problem description and solution]

If you see the solution of this problem, you can find out $p_Y(y) = 1/(8*\sqrt{y}) + δ(y)/2$. But I just can't understand why there's an $δ(y)/2$ in $p_Y(y)$. Could you tell me why $δ(y)/2$ is added to $1/(8*\sqrt{y})$? I've been trying to understand for three days, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nobody knows how to solve it?

Comment: You have a "lump" of probability (equal to 1/2) at zero which is what $\delta(y)/2$ is representing.  However, in this case not attempting to display the probability density function of $Y$ is not usually recognized as a legitimate probability density.  Displaying the cumulative distribution function would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: I think the appropriate result is to display the cumulative distribution function:  $$\begin{equation*}
 Pr(Y\leq y) =
 \begin{cases}
  0 & y<0 \\
  \frac{1}{2} & y=0 \\
  \frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{y}+2\right) & 0<y<4 \\
  1 & y\geq 4 \\
 \end{cases}       
\end{equation*}
$$.

Comment: I'm very much obliged to you, sir. So, did a δ(y)/2 in a Py(Y) come from a Px(X) when Px(X)'s duration is -2 <= x <= 2?

Comment: It came from $y=0$ when $x<0$ and $x<0$ occurs with probability $1/2$.